# How to handle in-app-purchase cancellations iOS (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

When a user completes a transaction (using the in-app-purchase package from flutter), I know I'm supposed to call:

`.completePurchase(Purchase)`

However when a user is prompted to purchase an item and they cancel, am I also supposed to call completePurchase?

I'm asking this because if the user then tries to buy the same non consumable product again in the same app session (app hasn't been closed), there is an output that reads:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(storekit_duplicate_product_object, There is a pending transaction for the same product identifier. Please either wait for it to be finished or finish it manually using completePurchase to avoid edge cases., {applicationUsername: null, requestData: null, quantity: 1, productIdentifier: 1, simulatesAskToBuyInSandbox: true}, null)
```

What is the solution to handling when:
`purchases[0].status == PurchaseStatus.canceled` ?

When I call `.completePurchase(Purchase)` on the cancelled transaction, everything seems to work fine meaning that the user can try again to buy the non-consumable product. But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle this situation

Answer (score 0):

This is how you handle it. You call completion only when the status is purchased or restored, otherwise it will throw an exception:

```
@override
void initState() {
  final Stream purchaseUpdated = InAppPurchase.instance.purchaseStream;
  _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) async {
    _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
  }, onDone: () {
    log('On Done Called');
  }, onError: (error) {
    log('On Error Called');
  });
  super.initState();
}

void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
  log('in App Purchase Listener Called');
  for (var purchaseDetails in purchaseDetailsList) {
    if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
      // _showPendingUI();
    } else {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
        log('Some Error While Purchasing ${purchaseDetails.error!}');
        //Handle Error Here
        // _handleError(purchaseDetails.error!);
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.canceled) {
        log('Purchase Cancelled');
        //Handle cancelled purchase
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
          purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
        //Deliver Product Here
        log('Product Purchased Or Restored');
        InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        //handle purchased product
      }
      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
    }
  }
}
```